# Share a SSD or RAMdisk between Google Compute Engine VMs

Tags: google-compute-engine

From google documentation it is clear that read-only Persistent Disk(PD) can be shared between multiple instances (Google compute VMs), but is it somehow possible to share SSD or RAM disk with multiple VMs?

Answer (score 2):

Local SSD are physically attached and they are, as well as RAM, **not** read-only.

So this question probably answers itself.